# window.location is undefined in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anybody knows why window.location is undefined in ie8 (maybe ie7 too), but works as document.location?

I couldn't find why another file, from other project has a similar code but hasn't a problem with IE.

I'm get a weird error too: 'window.location.hash is null or not an object in jquery 1.6.4 line 2'. I tried 1.5.1 too, but same error.

The header:

```
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

The JS part:

```
if( window.onhashchange )
{
    window.onhashchange = function()
    {
        hashChanged( window.location.hash );
    }
}
else
{
    var storedHash = window.location.hash;
    window.setInterval( function()
    {
        if( window.location.hash != storedHash )
        {
            storedHash = window.location.hash;
            hashChanged( storedHash );
        }
    }, 100 );
}
```

Comment: Are you missing `<!DOCTYPE html>` or did you not paste that?

Comment: Is it *just* an issue in IE? Or other browsers too? Do you have any variables named `location`?

Comment: Just IE. Was something like this, @Ӫ_._Ӫ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something in your project may be overriding `window.location`, though this won't work in IE 9:

```
var location;

alert(window.location);
//-> "undefined"
```

You could use the `delete` operator to delete the variable (although technically you shouldn't be able to, but it does work):

```
delete location;
```

But the best solution would be to look for the offending piece of code in your file.

Comment: I just confirmed this in IE8. That's some scary stuff.

Comment: I did something even worse 'window = $(document.window);'. Now, I see the mess. Why this bug-code works on other browsers?! Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a bug. This is by design, other browsers do it too. If you define a `var location` in the global scope, then it's a global variable and thus equivalent to `window.location`. Seems scary, and potentially dangerous, but understanding how JavaScript works shows it's technically correct behavior. I feel a little dumb, but what better way to learn? :)